# How do I copy a directory using Ganymed's SCPClient?

Tags: java, ssh

I need to recursively copy a directory (C:\test in this case) to a remote host. I tried the obvious:

```
conn.connect();
conn.authenticateWithPassword("user", "pw");
SCPClient scp = conn.createSCPClient();
scp.put("C:/test", "~/test");
conn.close();
```

but this gives the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error during SCP transfer.
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:577)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:535)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:430)
    at Test.Test.main(Test.java:57)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\test (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.sendFiles(SCPClient.java:190)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.SCPClient.put(SCPClient.java:573)
    ... 3 more
```

Am I missing something, or can Ganymed really only copy individual files, but not directories? Should I just `exec()` the appropriate scp command on the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging up the relevant parts of the souce code, I'm fairly certain the answer is "you don't".

All the `put()` methods that take one or more file names as parameters eventually call a private `sendFiles()` method to actually send the files. This method creates a `File` object from each filename, and then a [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29) object from each file. And sure enough, `FileInputStream`'s constructor throws a `FileNotFoundException` "if the file does not exist, **is a directory rather than a regular file**, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading." (And, apparently, it doesn't always throw it with the correct error message.)

---

**EDIT**: Though in all fairness, it's not at all hard to roll your own recursive function that copies a directory:

```
private static void putDir(Connection conn, String localDirectory, String remoteTargetDirectory, String mode) throws IOException {
    final String[] fileList = curDir.list();
    for (String file : fileList) {
        final String fullFileName = localDirectory + "/" + file;
        if (new File(fullFileName).isDirectory()) {
            final String subDir = remoteTargetDirectory + "/" + file;
            Session sess = conn.openSession();
            sess.execCommand("mkdir " + subDir);
            sess.waitForCondition(ChannelCondition.EOF, 0);
            putDir(conn, fullFileName, subDir, mode);
        }
        else {
            SCPClient scpc = conn.createSCPClient();
            scpc.put(fullFileName, remoteTargetDirectory, mode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, I understand the "putDir" function but what about "getDir". Is there any way to get list of files/directories in a directory on remote machine using scp client